# Display different webpage depending upon membership

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web, webserver

I am trying to create proposal for displaying different webpage depending upon user's membership.(e.g. Premium member - access to whole website, Normal member - cannot see certain tabs which are available only to premium members)

Answer (score 0):

So? The programming language that you are using to create those pages would have simple if/else statements; use those to control what is shown to the user.